# Is commutativity of the ring assumed in this argument?

Tags: ring-theory

Suppose x is a non-invertible element. Then the first observation is that (x) is a proper ideal, for if (x) = R, then in particular 1 belongs in (x) so 1 = ax contradiction the assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without commutativity "ideal" becomes ambiguous. It can mean "left ideal," "right ideal," or "two-sided ideal," and the argument fails in all three cases:

- In the left case, we get that there is some $a$ such that $1 = ax$, but this does not imply that $x$ is invertible in a noncommutative ring.
- Similarly, in the right case, we get that there is some $a$ such that $1 = xa$, but again this does not imply that $x$ is invertible in a noncommutative ring.
- Finally, in the two-sided case, the argument just can't get off the ground: the two-sided ideal generated by an element $x$ has all sorts of stuff in it, like elements of the form $ax, xa$, or even $axb$, etc.